# Automatic callback ladder creator

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

Suppose we have these two async functions:

```
function myfu(f) {
   setTimeout(function(){ f(true) }, 200) 
}

function myfu2(x, f) {
   setTimeout(function(){ f(500 + x) }, 200)
}
```

I was thinking about this syntax:

```
if (myfu.()) {
    var d = myfu2.(55)
    console.log(d) // outputs 555
}
```

which is amazingly simpler to type and read that this:

```
myfu(function (DOTCALL1) {
    if (DOTCALL1) {
        myfu2(55, function (DOTCALL2) {
            d = DOTCALL2
            console.log(d) // outputs 555
        })
    }
})
```

The conversion from `.(` syntax could be easily implemented by means of search/replace/regex.

I noticed that most of the time the result of my asynchronous functions is not used, and after it was called, the upper functions also exits immediately.

Although sometimes the upper function can do something after it called the first `async(callback)`, usually it does nothing. Sometimes the asynchronous function could return something useful, but most of the time it just returns `undefined` and real stuff is returned with `callback(result)`.

So I thought that maybe I could modify the code some how to make it easier to type and read. Which is illustrated by the example above.

My question is sipmle: is there already similar solution? I do not want to reinvent the wheel (if it is already invented). Or, if there is no such project, why not, why this approach, which seems so easy to implement and supposed to simplify development significantly is not used?

Please do not respond with the suggestion to "take a look at async.js". I am not asking about asynchronous programming patterns, asynchronous programming in general, not about arrow function notation =>, not about coffeScript. I am asking about a code conversion on the text level from proposed original syntax form to well known async ladder, aka "callback hell" notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are describing is very similar to streamline.js: https://github.com/Sage/streamlinejs.

I wrote it but I got the idea from narrative.js: See http://www.neilmix.com/narrativejs/doc/

So your intuition is right. This can be done. It is nevertheless a little more complicated than a few search/replace/regex operations, at least if you want to go beyond the obvious and support async calls in all JavaScript constructs. For example, try to rewrite:

```
while (asyncF1.() && asyncF2.()) asyncF3.();
```

I described the streamline transformation algorithm in a blog post: https://bjouhier.wordpress.com/2011/05/24/yield-resume-vs-asynchronous-callbacks/

Comment: I just wrote my naive implementation https://github.com/exebook/dotcall, but it will not handle such cases of course.

Answer (score 1):

I have this site bookmarked since last year where the author blogs about EcmaScript6 which allegedly allows you to obtain something similar to .NET's `async` / `await` pattern (so allowing code to invoke asynchronous methods like a "normal" one). [Here is the link](https://bjouhier.wordpress.com/2013/06/01/bringing-asyncawait-to-life-in-javascript/)

> ES6 introduces two small extensions to the language syntax:
>
> function*: the functions that you declare with a little twinkling star are generator functions. They execute in an unusual way and return generators.
>
> yield: this keyword lets you transfer control from a generator to the function that controls it.
>
> And, even though these two language constructs were not orginally designed to have the async/await semantics found in other languages, it is possible to give them these semantics:
>
> The * in function* is your async keyword.
>
> yield is your await keyword.
>
> Knowing this, you can write asynchronous code as if JavaScript had async/await keywords.

I never had the chance to try it out though, so YMMV. It *sounds* useful.